# Deleted Outlook messages stay on screen

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have just installed Office 2010 and in my Outlook when I delete a message, it stays on the screen with a line through it rather than go into the trash.  What setting would control putting it into the trash automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You may be in luck because Outlook 2010's handling of IMAP is better than in previous versions but is still pretty stinky.

The first step is to hold the deleted messages that have the line through them.  Ckick on View and then Change View and you'll see

[image]

Click the "Hide Mess..." button.

Next, open the Mail option in your Windows Control Panel (alternatively click File and then Account Settings within Outlook), double click on your IMAP account, Click More Settings and then click the Deleted Items tab.  On shown in the screenshot below you can select "Move deleted items to the following folder..." and pick whichever folder you like.  This option wasn't available in prior versions of Outlook.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you're using IMAP instead of POP3.

When you tell `Deleted Items` to empty (or change the settings to do this for you in the Outlook options), it should clear from the screen.